# ListView Item Detail Screen: New or Same Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a listview where each item correlates to an instance of an item in an array. When the user selects an item, it will bring up a 'Details' page that reads and displays other data members of the list item.

Would this be better implemented with the Details page as its own activity, or a new view within the same activity? Pros and cons of each?

A new activity makes my job a little easier in terms of handling the 'back' button, but then I have the challenge of how do I pass the rest of the data structure to the new activity since I can't bundle it up (unless I serialize it).

******EDIT**** Essentially I have a Playlist where the list item shows the title, 
item number, and an icon. Clicking on the item will show a full item description screen. I'm leaning toward containing that within the playlist activity since all that data is contained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want it done, I recommend using a new activity for things with a lot of information; especially if yoy need some interactivity such as links.

Pro's with this are mainly the flow of the application. the user can use the back button to navigate easier.

Con's being having to have a whole new activity to view details

If you are, however, just extending a description you could use a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you want to be able to call that item from somewhere else possibly, then breaking it off to a separate Activity is the way to go.  As far as how to get the data in there, why not just pass the Intent with an id of the item and then load it from your datastore based off of the id.

Answer (score 0):

> but then I have the challenge of how
>   do I pass the rest of the data
>   structure to the new activity since I
>   can't bundle it up (unless I serialize
>   it).

Or, move your model outside of the initial `Activity`. For example, you could have your list be held by a `Service` that each `Activity` binds to, and have it manage the model. Or, have the model be held in static data members (though watch out for GC issues). Or, if eventually this will be in a database, get it to the database now, then just pass the key to the item via an extra, so the detail activity can get it from the database.

Comment: For application globals I've been subclassing Application and using fields within that. However pulling my playlist items out of my playlist-related activities would be a big break of convention. Gotta think about this one.